# Remove timezone from web service response

Tags: java, .net, web-services, date

Is there any way to remove the timezone component from a Java Date object that is being returned from a web service?

For example I have a start Date of 12AM.  I want that to be used as 12AM local time of the clients.

I think that if the soap message doesn't have a timezone component then the local timezone is used.  There are 2 other options that I have weighed which would be either doing arithmetic on the date on the client side (which I really really do not want to do) or creating a new date class that holds the day, month and year as integers(I don't need the time information).  The latter option would require substantial refactoring so if there is a way to just chop off the timezone info in the soap message that would be preferable.

The client is written in .NET so if there is a way to change the how the date is interpreted on the client side that would achieve the same goal i think.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have found a solution to my problem.  I used @XmlJavaTypeAdapter to change the way the date class is marshaled to Xml.

Here is the DateAdapter I used.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {
 // the desired format
 private String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";

 public String marshal(Date date) throws Exception {
 return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(date);
 }

 public Date unmarshal(String dateString) throws Exception {
 return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(dateString);
 }
}
```

And I used the following annotation on all of my getters that I wanted to use the "yyyy-MM-dd" date format.

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=DateAdapter.class, type=Date.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

Java `Date` objects don't *have* time zone components. They have no concept of time zones at all: they're always just milliseconds since midnight January 1st 1970, UTC.

I don't know much about the SOAP representation of dates and times... if you can persuade it that a *date* is all you need (rather than a date and time) you may well be fine. Otherwise, I suggest you do everything in UTC but *consider* it to be the local time on the client. If you're only dealing with dates, this shouldn't be too bad - although you do need to consider that midnight doesn't always occur on every date in every time zone, or it may occur twice...

Basically it's a pity that neither .NET nor Java has a decent built-in date and time API. On Java there's [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) where you'd want to use `LocalDate` by the sounds of it, to represent *exactly* what you're interested in (a date in whatever the local time zone is). On .NET there *will* (eventually) be [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) but that isn't ready yet. Even if both of these existed in the respective base platforms, you'd still need to persuade SOAP to serialize them appropriately :(